# PostGIS vs Postgresql Performance in normal tables

Tags: postgresql, postgis

i have a question that i couldn't find an answer for searching in my own, and i thank you for your help in advance.

Is it better to create the non spatial tables & relations in PostGIS Database with spatial tables, or To create special tables in PostGIS and create non spatial tables & relations in normal PostgreSQL database, and if the we go with the latter choice how to properly do it?

Comment: I don't understand the question. PostGIS is an _extension_ to Postgres it is not a separate "database product". Once you have installed the extension in your Postgres database you simply use the additional data types and functions (as if they were built-in from the start)

Comment: Thank you very much, i thought there will be performance penalty using postgis in normal tables, thank you and have a good day